# How to use CORS with grails rest API?

Tags: rest, api, grails, cors

I am developing Rest Api using grails. It is working on localhost:8080. when I am calling with POSTMAN it responded with json. I want to use this data and also perform CRUD operation on my web page which is running on other domain. When I am trying to call RESTAPI which is written in grails, the browser is not able to get a response due to Access-Control-Allow-Origin. So how to enable CORS functionality in my REST API, So anyone can access from a different domain.

Comment: You need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to the response of your API. See this explanation to understand how CORS works: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Grails 3.2.1 or higher, it comes with CORS support built in.

In your `application.yml`, add the following:

```
grails:
    cors:
        enabled: true
```

See http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/introduction.html#whatsNewCors for further details.

Comment: Ya. I tried it and added a dependency in application.yml  and it is working fine.